# QGIS: Exporting/saving extents of WMS raster layer in a batch process

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, geotiff-tiff, batch

In QGIS is it possible to run: Export -> Save As as a batch command?

I have WMS-raster layers from which I'd like to extract certain extents (based on quite a number of features from a vector layer) and save them as GeoTIFF fur further statistical analyses. As it is a WMS service, I cannot use "Clip Raster by Extent" (or at least I don't know how). Saving the data for each vector feature extent manually is quite time-consuming, so I'd like to run it as batch function.

Comment: you could make the requests directly to the WMS server using curl in a batch file if you have a list of bounding boxes